# Следование интерфейса за камерой в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, gui, ui, камера

Я создаю 2d игру, в которой камера следует за персонажем (то есть позиция камеры равна позиции персонажа). Также в игре есть интерфейс, реализованный через canvas.

Проблема в том, что при смещении камеры интерфейс остаётся стоять на месте, а мне нужно чтобы он был всегда в определенной позиции относительно камеры.

Я могу сделать canvas дочерним объектом камеры, но будет ли это правильно? Есть ли способ лучше?

Comment: Какой `Render Mode` у вашего канваса? Вам нужен `Screen Space - Overlay`

Comment: У меня Screen Space - Camera. Я сделал так, чтобы размер канваса автоматически приравнивался к размеру камеры

Comment: @МихаилМуратов да он в любом моде отталкивается от камеры, а каким образом настраивается в компаненте скалирования. Вам нужен `Screen Space - Overlay`.

Comment: Ок,  я попробую.